# No irq handler error while installing Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: system-installation, 20.04

While installing Ubuntu 20.04 on a new computer, I encountered a `No irq handler` error. After booting from an USB drive and selecting install Ubuntu, the no irq handler message showed up a few times followed by screen artifacts.

[image: error message]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: @Pilot6 I'd prefer to keep this question open if this is OK with you because the OP's solution seems to be specific for fixing the `No irq handler for vector` boot message especially when it is accompanied by visual artifacts as it is in the screen photo in the question.

Answer (score 5):

After further research, I found a reddit user with the same problem as me. The solution is to boot Ubuntu under safe graphics mode. The error would still occur but it will boot into Ubuntu after a while.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what worked for me - When in the GNU option screen, while at the Ubuntu installation option, press <kbd>E</kbd>.

This would open up an editable file with the kernel parameters. In the line with `splash --` at the end, type `nomodeset` right after the space after splash (e.g. `splash nomodeset --`).

Do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>. Ubuntu will now be installed and you'll not get the same error message. I have an NVIDIA GeForce GPU which most likely caused the problem (something about latest drivers, I'm still unclear why though).

Answer (score 1):

if you are using a msi motherboard this is a issue with the iommu setting need to be disabled in bios i have a msi gaming edg wifi once disable it no longer shows i am also using a ryzen 3200g with onboard graphics. I found that this was a problem with some intel manufactures and as well as some amd so disable it should and you should no longer get the errors

On systems with the Intel 5500 and 5520 chipsets (revision 0x13) and the Intel X58 chipset (revisions 0x12, 0x13, 0x22), having interrupt remapping enabled causes various problems.
The reported symptoms range from network link state flapping and partial to full loss of communication on network cards.

Common is that the kernel will log messages like
"kernel: do_IRQ: x.xxx No irq handler for vector (irq -1)"
in the syslog.

Answer (score 1):

I was over this same issue for 3 days, formatting and reformatting with no progress.

I will suggest installing the ubuntu from a live usb using the OEM manufacturers option. It should boot successfully and you can do all needful setting afterwards