# Trouble installing Lubuntu/Ubuntu on old laptop with Windows 10

Tags: system-installation, lubuntu

I am trying to install Lubuntu on a Toshiba Satelite laptop. When I boot from the flash drive that has the image on it and try to install, I get two error messages:

```
[    0.004964] __common_interrupt: 1.55 No irq handler for vector
[    2.352043] integrity: Problem loading X.509 certificate -65
```

Just to check that it wasn't Lubuntu that was causing the problem, I also attempted to install Ubuntu Desktop with the same results.

I have tried various answers I found on Google without success. For the `No irq handler for vector` error:

- [No irq handler error while installing Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1258283/no-irq-handler-error-while-installing-ubuntu-20-04)

  - I tried selecting the Safe Graphics mode, which resulted in the same error (and unlike the answer on the above question, it did not eventually boot into Lubuntu/Ubuntu).
  - I tried editing the command and adding `nomodeset` before trying to boot. No change.
- https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1234983

  - I tried adding the option `pci=nomsi,noaer` to the command with no success.

For the `Problem loading X.509 certificate -65` error:

Most sources say that I should disable secure boot to get it going, but doing so does nothing to get rid of this error.

I can't seem to figure out either of the above errors so that I can continue with installation. Is there a troubleshooting step I haven't tried before that could fix these?

UPDATE:

In answer to the comments, here is some more information about the computer:

Toshiba Satellite C855D-S5357

CPU: AMD E-300 APU with Radeon Graphics, 1.3 GHz

RAM: 4GB

Graphics: AMD Radeon HD 6310 Graphics

If it's relevant also, it currently has Windows 10 installed, but the system can't handle it to the point of being unusable. That's just one of many reasons to install Linux instead.

Comment: Please tell us the model of your Toshiba Satellite, and if possible also the CPU brand name and model, the amount of RAM and the graphics (chip/card). (I have a Toshiba Satellite bought 2013 with Intel i5 generation 3 CPU, 4 GB RAM and Intel graphics (no separate graphics processor). It works well with all current versions of Ubuntu.)

Comment: I edited it to add the requested details @sudodus

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I have an answer. See [this link](https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/1mzbds/installing_ubuntu_on_toshiba_satellite_c855ds5201/).

According to that link, your computer is probably booting in UEFI mode, and if you switch in the BIOS to CSM (alias BIOS mode alias legacy mode), the graphics will probably work for you. At least it did 8 years ago (with Ubuntu).

> It turns out the option to change between UEFI and CSM was buried
> under a sub-menu that I didn't see at first. Changing it allowed
> Ubuntu to run. Thanks for you help!

I have a similar version of Toshiba, but with Intel CPU, and I think the UEFI/BIOS system is the same or similar:

- Press F12
- Select <Enter Setup>
- Select 'Advanced'
- Select 'System Configuration'
- Press the <Enter> key and get to the menu where you switch between UEFI and CSM Boot
- Press F10 to save the new setting and reboot

Comment: That did the trick, thanks a lot! Glad I was able to find someone that had been through a similar experience!

Comment: I'm glad I could help you. As a matter of fact, my computer, that is quite similar to yours has been used for several years to test the developing versions of Ubuntu before and at the release. It is very convenient to open it and replace the HDD with a modern and nowadays very cheap SATA SSD.

Comment: I have a very similar Toshiba, with Windows 8.
This did the trick for me.
Now I would like to install Lubuntu with dual boot, would you think booting from DVD and following the regular installation procedure would work?

Comment: Yes, I think so, @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio.

Comment: As per [this question and comments thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1371926/recover-grub-dual-boot-uefi-windows-8-csm-installed-lubuntu-20-04?noredirect=1#comment2359855_1371926), it seems for dual booting with a preexisting Windows UEFI-booted partition this answer might not be the best option.
I don't know which one *is*.

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio, The problem of *this thread* is that graphics [of Ubuntu family flavours] do not work in UEFI mode. My Toshiba has an Intel CPU with built-in graphics, and it works (but with some quirks) both in BIOS mode and UEFI mode. If your computer is more like mine you can install Lubuntu in UEFI mode and need not re-install Windows. But if it is more like the computer of the OP of this thread, Lubuntu might work only in BIOS mode. Finally, there might be another and better solution, if you find a firmware upgrade, that makes the graphics work also in UEFI mode.

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio, I should also mention, that it is possible to install Lubuntu in BIOS mode even when Windows is installed in UEFI mode. It works, but makes it more cumbersome to switch between the operating systems, because you must also switch boot mode in an UEFI/BIOS menu.

Comment: @sudodus - 
1) Do you mean that the problem stems from a particular combination of Graphics card + OS (Ubuntu here) + UEFI mode? If I am with one such case, would you think there is any way of succeeding with item 2 below (without reinstalling Windows, and preferably not Lubuntu either)?
2) That is exactly what I do (and I posted that in the OP). But now I want to get both OSs in grub, so I don't have to enter BIOS to switch OS.

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio, 1) Yes, I think the problem stems from a particular combination of Graphics card + OS (Ubuntu here) + UEFI mode. I don't know if you can make Lubuntu work in UEFI mode in that computer or if you can convert the existing Windows system into BIOS boot mode (legacy mode). **You can try if you have a good backup** according to item 2). Oldfred, who is helping you in the other thread, knows more than I about booting. Read very carefully his advice.